# What is the concentration/molecules per cell of iodothyronine deiodinase in a cell?

Tags: biochemistry, endocrinology, enzyme-kinetics, pharmacokinetics, kinetics

I'm trying to parameterize an in silico model and need the approximate concentration (M), or molecules per cell, of iodothyronine deiodinase type II (D2) enzyme in a human cell, ideally a glial cell.  I can only find specific activity values in the literature. Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?